# What is the Microsoft Enterprise Application Blocks relationship to the ASP.NET provider model?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, enterprise-library

What is the Microsoft Enterprise Application Blocks relationship to the ASP.NET provider model? (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise library have a Security Application Block.

It exposes two interfaces that you can access in your code:

An Authorization Provider interface, which exposes the single method named Authorize that takes an instance of an IPrincipal object containing details of the user's identity and roles. Depending on the way that you configure the block, the authorization can take place either through Windows® Authorization Manager (AzMan) against Active Directory, an XML file, or a database; or by using custom rules that you define and are stored as XML in the application configuration file. 
A Security Cache Provider interface, which exposes methods that allow you to save and retrieve a user's identity or security context as an IIdentity instance, IPrincipal instance, or ASP.NET Profile instance. Each cached identity or security context is identified by a token (by default a GUID, though you can create and use your own implementation of the IToken interface). The block stores this information in either a database or in Isolated Storage using the Caching Application Block. You can alternatively create a custom provider for the Caching Application Block and use it to cache the information in the location and using the techniques you implement in your provider.

Then you also can reference ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa479030.aspx